# Counting words in a string in C

Tags: c, string, word-count

I have written a block of code to count how many words a string consists of.

I've already tried multiple inputs and most of them come out correct but there are cases indicating my program has a fundamental logic flaw. For instance if I set in an empty string, the output will wrongly be 1 and if I add whitespace right in the end of the string , for some reason I don't know the output will be 1+the actual number of the words within the string and as my code obviously demonstrates I would like to take out all whitespaces/tabs .

My program basically does so amidst a string but unfortunately doesn't at the end of it. It is pretty clear to me there is something wrong with my function but I can't figure out what. And I know it probably can be more easily implemented with the aid of external libraries but I am asked to implement it with pure basic code.

This is what I have so far:

```
int get_number_of_words(char input_string[])
{
    int i, j, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < STRING_SIZE; i++)
    {
        if (input_string[i] != ' ')
        {
            counter++;
            j = i;
            while ((input_string[j] != ' '))
                j++;
            i = j;
        }
    }
    return counter;
}
```

I'll give you a few examples of input and output strings :

- `"Hello\t\t\t"` - 1 word (tabs ignored)
- `"Hello"` - 1 word
- `""` - 0 words
- `"\t\tThis is a basic example\t\t\t"` - 5 words (tabs ignored)
- `"This is a basic example "` - 5 words as well (final space ignored)

Later on,I'll have to take distinct punctuation marks (that are included within the words) into account but in the meantime all I want is to grasp the core of the program.

Comment: Can you include some input strings, and (expected) output? The problem description is quite clear, but I'm unsure about e.g. tabs, line breaks, and problems in your current code. In- and output would clarify these immensely.

Comment: spaces which occur at the end or at the beginning, space characters such as newline or tab is problematic. These characters can occur successively as well as between alphanumeric characters. Also, these characters might be OS dependent

Comment: Undefined behavior for accessing beyond the bounds of an object.

Comment: If you have two whitespace together your program will count two words, you could try using an int as a bool to control that

Comment: What if `input_string` points to a string literal or `char` array less than `SIZE_STRING`? Then you have undefined behavior reading beyond the bounds of the referenced `char` array or string literal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just looking for a working algorithm, here is the logic:

1. Separate/Split the sentence/(string of words) using whitespace. The outcome will be an array.
2. Filter the array to remove any blank strings (whitespaces), unwanted words like 'is' 'a' 'an'.
3. Count the length of resulting array.

That should be your answer. I hope you can convert the instructions into a program.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the modified code. Please refer comments for better understanding. I also assumed that STRING_SIZE will be bigger then length of input string.

```
int get_number_of_words(char input_string[])
{
    int i, j, counter = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < STRING_SIZE; i++)
    {
        // This makes sure that when the 'i' in input_string is reached to end,
        // you must not check further. It is basically last char of string.
        if(input_string[i]=='\0')break;

        // only enter this if condition if encounter a char a-z or A-Z
        if((input_string[i]>='A'&&input_string[i]<='Z')||(input_string[i]>='a'&&input_string[i]<='z'))
        {
            counter++;
            j = i;
            // if there is no ' ' then this loop will run forever.
            // thus added a constraint. 
            // iterate this loop till you read char from a-z or A-Z
            while (j<STRING_SIZE && ((input_string[j]>='A'&&input_string[j]<='Z')||(input_string[j]>='a'&&input_string[j]<='z')))
                j++;
            i = j;
        }

    }
    return counter;
}
```

Comment: This code works for all your sample test cases. And also runs for my own test cases.

Answer (score 0):

Using a loop like:

```
for (i = 0; i < STRING_SIZE; i++)
```

seems a bad idea. I assume that STRING_SIZE is some fixed number set in a `#define` which won't work as the input string can be both shorter and longer.

Instead I suggest that you use a pointer to iterate the string, i.e. initialize the pointer to point to start of string and in each loop increment the pointer and continue the loop until you see the string termination.

That could look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int is_whitespace(char c)
{
    // Check for space or tab
    return (c == ' ' || c == '\t');
}

int get_number_of_words(char* input_string)
{
    int counter = 0;

    // Make p point to start of string
    char* p = input_string;

    // Remove whitespaces, i.e. look for next word or end-of-string
    while (*p && is_whitespace(*p)) ++p;

    while(*p)
    {
        ++counter;

        // Continue down the string until a whitespace or end-of-string is found
        while(*p && !is_whitespace(*p)) ++p;

        // Remove whitespaces, i.e. look for next word or end-of-string
        while (*p && is_whitespace(*p)) ++p;
    }
    return counter;
}


int main()
{
    char* str1 = "some text";
    printf("%s %d\n", str1, get_number_of_words(str1));
    char* str2 = "         some                   text                  ";
    printf("%s %d\n", str2, get_number_of_words(str2));
    char* str3 = "some\ttext";
    printf("%s %d\n", str3, get_number_of_words(str3));
    char* str4 = "\tsome\t\ttext\t\t";
    printf("%s %d\n", str4, get_number_of_words(str4));
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
some text 2
         some                   text                   2
some    text 2
    some        text         2
```